# NavigationView frame glitch with safearea

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I try to create a custom ViewModifier similar to SwiftUI's .sheet modifier.

When I try to make a NavigationView spring from bottom, the frame of the view just glitched over safearea. The frame looks as if adjust to the safearea when the view moves from bottom to top.

Anyone knows maybe how to constrain the view frame inside the navigation view to avoid this?

Here is what happened. When click the plus button, the SwiftUI .sheet modifier shows up. Custom popup shows up when pressing the gear button.
[Problem gif recording here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8bpP.gif)

Here is code of the custom popup view.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @Binding var showingSelf: Bool
    @Binding var retryWrongCards: Bool
        
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    Section {
                        Toggle(isOn: $retryWrongCards) {
                            Text("Retry Wrong Cards")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .animation(nil)
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") {
                    self.showingSelf = false
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code of custom modifier

```
struct Popup<T: View>: ViewModifier {
    let popup: T
    let isPresented: Bool

    init(isPresented: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> T) {
        self.isPresented = isPresented
        popup = content()
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(popupContent())
    }

    @ViewBuilder private func popupContent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if isPresented {
                popup
                    .animation(.spring())
                    .transition(.offset(x: 0, y: geometry.belowScreenEdge))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension GeometryProxy {
    var belowScreenEdge: CGFloat {
        UIScreen.main.bounds.height - frame(in: .global).minY
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are not using your geometry reader...

Comment: It is not really clear what "glitch" you mean and whether it is related to your custom sheet modifier or the unused `GeometryReader`. Perhaps you post also the code of your custom sheet modifier? Is it based on Apples `sheet` modifier? Or are you simply covering the screen (using the GeometryReader) with a `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))` modifier?

Comment: @pd95 hi I was referring to the NavigationView when pressing the gear button. I was trying to solve this with geometry.size.width, but the NavigationBarItem still overlaps with the safearea. When animated, the view shrinks horizontally and then expands again. I was using .transition() to move the view. I added the view modifier code above.

Comment: Hi Ben, another question from me :-). I see that you are testing on a iPhone 11/12 in landscape mode. Therefore you expect the "safe area" on the left and right side to be respected, which is the case in your "EditCards" screen, but not in your "Settings" screen. So I have the following questions: is your EditCards screen using your custom sheet modifier? Or is only the Settings screen using the modifier? Further: are you testing on a device or only in the simulator?

Comment: Hi @BenLin, I think I can reproduce your problem reliably in my own version of "FlashZilla" and can confirm that during the transition (in or out) of the popup, the content of the `NavigationView` does not respect the safe area insets. For me, they only "pop-in" after the transition has finished animating. This does not happen with the regular `.sheet` modifier.

Comment: Hi @pd95, thanks for asking. I was using the iPhone XR for testing. The EditCards screen is using `.sheet` modifier, and the Settings screen is using the custom one. By putting the `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` outside of `NavigationView `solves the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging and trying many changes, I was already preparing a mini-project to file a SwiftUI bug for Apple. In the end, it was not necessary and we have a simple solution !!

**TLDR;** your `SettingsView` does not correctly initialise the `NavigationView`.
The modifier `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` has to be applied onto the `NavigationView` and not inside it (in contrast to `navigationBarTitle` or `navigationBarItems` which only work when put inside the `NavigationView`):

```swift
NavigationView {
    List {
        Section {
            Toggle(isOn: $retryWrongCards) {
                Text("Retry Wrong Cards")
            }
        }
    }
    .animation(nil)
    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done") {
        self.showingSelf = false
    })
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

After this change your custom sheet modifier behaves for me identically as the regular `.sheet` modifier! Great work!
Philipp

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks! It now looks exactly like the .sheet modifier.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your animation does exactly what a sheet does. I would just replace it with that. You can easily present a sheet on top of a sheet.

**Edit**

After you posted your ViewModifier code, it seems the only difference is the animation type and the size of the popup.

Comment: Right... I'm trying to build a custom popup view modifier so that I can use it in different places with different transition animations.